# Trying to take which radio button is selected and when is put it through code is returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm new to JavaScript and trying to get a radio button to be registered on variable and then have that variable return another var but it just keeps being returned undefined. If I'm just doing something overtly wrong please tell me.

The **radio** buttons

`Fighter:<input type="radio" id="fig" value="1"/>

 Cleric:<input type="radio" id="cleric" value="2"/>

 Sorcerer:<input type="radio" id="wiz" value="3"/>`

my **js**

```
var lvl
var bab
if (document.getElementById('fig').checked) {
var cass = document.getElementById('fig').value;
if (cass == 1){
bab = 1;
} 
else if (cass == 2){
bab = 2;
} 
else{
bab = 3;
} 
}

function show(){
var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
txtOutput.value = bab;
}
```

And my final place its supposed to be submitting.

```
<input id="txtOutput">
    </input>
```

Comment: when you want insert radio button value to textbox? ex: on_change of radio?

Comment: @javedrathod no i need to have the values eventually work out the multiple variables. I am trying to get the value to process an if statement that will depend on the value. sorry is does not make since i have not gone to sleep in the past two days

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you clarity.

```js
var lvl = "";
var bab = "";

function getValues() {
  if (document.getElementById('fig').checked) {
    bab = "1 : " + document.getElementById('fig').value + "\n";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('cleric').checked) {
    bab += "2 : " + document.getElementById('cleric').value + "\n";
  }
  
  if((document.getElementById('wiz').checked)){
    bab += "3 : " + document.getElementById('wiz').value;
  }
  
  show();
}

function show(){
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  txtOutput.innerHTML = bab;
}

/* or you can call it when you click on it */
function consoleIt(obj) {
  console.log(obj.id + " : " + obj.value);
 }
```

```html
Fighter  : <input type="radio" onclick="consoleIt(this);" id="fig" value="1"/>
Cleric   : <input type="radio" onclick="consoleIt(this);" id="cleric" value="2"/>
Sorcerer : <input type="radio" onclick="consoleIt(this);" id="wiz" value="3"/>
<button onclick="getValues();">Get Radio Data</button>
<textarea id="txtOutput"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Add `change` event listener for all `radio` inputs and on `change` of the input, set the value of the textbox.

[`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) Returns a list of the elements within the document that match the specified group of selectors.

Try this:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[name="name"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById("txtOutput").value = this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
Fighter:
<input type="radio" id="fig" value="1" name='name' />Cleric:

<input type="radio" id="cleric" value="2" name='name' />Sorcerer:

<input type="radio" id="wiz" value="3" name='name' />

<br>

<input id="txtOutput">
```